# Error in a codeigniter web app into cpanel though is working perfectly in a local server

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am getting an error when i uploaded the files into the cpanel the code is down here...
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 347

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'exampleuser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'examplepassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'uhuruone_amref';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: it required the username and password if i remove it wont work by the way they are just examples

Comment: yes i have removed and doent work

Answer (score 0):

In cpannel actually username and database name has cpanel username prefix eg

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'cpanelusername_root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cpanelusername_db name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; ///use this extension
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

in more simple words

```
Host = localhost (literally put localhost)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (******)
```

Comment: thanks but the code i have runs in local server when uploading in cpanel doesnt work

Comment: yeah i have that problem too when you upload your code to cpannel just change database settings in application/config/database.php as above whatever your username like kid is username of cpannel  then put username as kid_root and database name as kid_database name @user3551487

Comment: so hostname shouldnt be localhost?

Comment: @user3551487 my mistake it should be localhost

Comment: i have changed the password username to match the ones i created in cpanel aswell as the database name

Comment: @user3551487 just change settings as above

Comment: edit question what you have done the changes you have made @user3551487